# combining the list of lists of varying length with a fixed list

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, tidyr

I have a data which I want to merge which has list of lists of unequal length. For example

```
 A<- c("AA-1234", "AA-1245", "AA-12445")

B<- c( c("1", "2", "34", "aab5"), c("a3", "3e"), c(""))
```

So A and B have equal number of rows and the first row in A is the id number and the elements of rows B are respective responses. You can see that the elements of for "AA-1234" there are 4 elements and for "AA-1234" there are 2 elements. I would like to have dataset as follows:

```
   A         B
AA-1234      1
AA-1234      2
AA-1234      34
AA-1234      aab5
AA-1245      a3
AA-1245      3e
AA-12445
```

Any suggestions?

```
 B<- list(c("1", "2", "34", "aab5"), c("a3", "3e"), c(""))
```

Comment: `B` is not list of list. It's a simple vector

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to program that. I see in my dataset as c{"1". "2"). c("233") etc in the rows..Please advise how to change/edit that

Comment: Use `dput` to share an actual subset of your data, i.e. `dput(your_object)`

Comment: it is quite massive it has like 25 records for the first row and 20 for next and it has around 1214 rows ..

Comment: You can do `dput(head(data))`

Comment: It is a list..I have added that information

Comment: I was getting an invalid times argument when I used the previous solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)

A<- c("AA-1234", "AA-1245", "AA-12445")

B<- c( list(c("1", "2", "34", "aab5")), list(c("a3", "3e")), list(""))




as_tibble(cbind(A,B)) %>%  
  mutate(A = unlist(A)) %>% 
  unnest(B)


# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   A        B    
# <chr>    <chr>
# 1 AA-1234  1    
# 2 AA-1234  2    
# 3 AA-1234  34   
# 4 AA-1234  aab5 
# 5 AA-1245  a3   
# 6 AA-1245  3e   
# 7 AA-12445 ""
```